# How to change color of a part of a ellipse?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I think (hope) this is a very simple question and I only stuck because of my bad knowledge about Adobe Illustrator...
I have drawn a circle using the ellipse tool and colored only the outline. My question is: Is there an easy way to color specific parts of this outline in different colors?

I have read about the Live Paint function, but as I told, I'm not really familiar to this...

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Have you tried looking into the Adobe Illustrator User Guide? It's well worth reading software instruction manuals when you're starting... https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/live-paint-groups.html

Answer (score 2):

There are several methods you could try. Since the other answer already mentions gradients, here are some other ways to do it.

This is just an ellipse which has been cut at each anchor, and each segment has a different stroke colour applied.

[image]

Another method is to use a black ellipse as an opacity mask over some areas of colour. In this example I used a wide brush to create them, but any blocks of colour will do. I grouped these and applied the black outlined circle as a mask to the group.

[image]

Here's another version using a gradient along a stroke, it's self explanatory really.

[image]

Comment: The black ellipse as a mask sounds interesting... can you may elaborate this method? How do I set a wide brush?

Comment: @user141333 Choose the brush tool, then you can change its size by pressing the square bracket keys. To make a mask,  select both the group and the object that will be the mask. Open the Appearance panel, and then click on "Opacity default" (as shown in the screenshot) and press Make mask.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Gradiant tool to customise multiple color of your elipse. Can be found under **Windows** > **Gradient**. Play around with the Type, Stroke and Colors (Represented with the arrows in the picture bellow).

Make sure to have selected the Border (On the left of the stroke setting), since by default it can select the Fill, which is a common starter mistake.

[image]